# How to disable copying the shapes present in chartarea?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, shapes, vba

I have a chart in Excel where my macro populates 10 shapes by the right side of the chart area. I want to copy only the chart to the power point and could not find a way to disable copying the shapes so far. If I copy the chart, it copies the shapes as well.

Comment: Are the shapes inside the chart object? If they are inside the chart object then they will get copied with the chart. A solution would be to cut them out of the chart and paste them over the chart (but not in it). When you export the chart (by referencing the object) these shapes should not get copied with your chart.

Comment: Or you can copy/paste the chart, and then delete the shapes from the pasted chart by looping through each shape in the Shapes collection of the Chart object.

Comment: Yes, the shapes are present in chart object. I have these ideas in mind. Looking for a user friendly way out without extra work to the user. Tried $.controlformat.printobject =false $ not working... Looking for something to add in VBA to restrict copying the shapes.. is it possible... @domenic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example that copies the first chart from the active sheet, pastes it to the first slide of the active presentation, and deletes any existing shapes from the pasted chart...

```
'Declare Excel variables
Dim ChartObj As ChartObject

'Declare PowerPoint variables
Dim ppApp As Object
Dim ppPres As Object
Dim ppChartObj As Object
Dim ppShape As Object

'Copy first chart from active sheet
Set ChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
ChartObj.Copy

'Paste chart into first slide of active presentation
Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation
Set ppChartObj = ppPres.slides(1).Shapes.Paste(1)

'Delete shapes from chart
For Each ppShape In ppChartObj.Chart.Shapes
    ppShape.Delete
Next ppShape
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this idea. This helped.